# How can I add an instance of an UserControl to the "stage" in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, flash, silverlight, actionscript, object

I really searched for a long time to get the clue how to add an instance of a custom UserControl Object, that I created to the Silverlight "stage", but I didn't find anything.

Is there anything in Silverlight with C# like "Stage.addChild(myAweseomeObject);" in Flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Jesse Liberty's page on [Creating Controls in Code](http://jesseliberty.com/2008/05/05/creating-controls-in-code/):

```
Button button2 = new Button(); 
button2.Width = 75; 
button2.Height = 30; 
button2.Content = "No, click me!"; 
button2.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0); 
button2.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1); 
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(button2);
```

You'd do the same thing with your own user control.  Just replace "new Button()" with the name of your user control, e.g. "new MyUserControl()".

So a simplified version may be something like this:

```
AwesomeControl _AwesomeControl = new AwesomeControl();
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(_AwesomeControl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight or Flash?

Flash has the `addChild` method.

oops.. I understood the question wrongly.